# How do I fix this error when creating a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm following a tutorial to create ruby gems http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

The tutorial tells me to create a ruby file like this:

```
% cat lib/hola.rb
class Hola
  def self.hi
    puts "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

Then a gemspec file like this:

```
% cat hola.gemspec
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'hola'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2010-04-28'
  s.summary     = "Hola!"
  s.description = "A simple hello world gem"
  s.authors     = ["Nick Quaranto"]
  s.email       = 'nick@quaran.to'
  s.files       = ["lib/hola.rb"]
  s.homepage    =
    'http://rubygems.org/gems/hola'
end
```

When I `gem build hola.gemspec` I get this error:

```
Invalid gemspec in [hola.gemspec]: hola.gemspec:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
% cat hola.gemspec
      ^
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
```

Now his code on Github will not build without the Rakefile.

So how can I make this work? Do I need to add a Rakefile or is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: creating using bundler https://shivab.com/blog/ruby/2019/08/30/convert-your-ruby-script-to-a-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error indicates that your file has the line `% cat hola.gemspec` in it literally. This line in the example isn't intended to be part of the file itself; it's the Unix command the author used to print the contents of the file. Remove that line and the similar line from the other file and you should be OK to move to the next step.

Comment: Ya I wondered why ruby-docs didn't say anything about a cat command. How embarrassing. Clears things up though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first line, `% cat lib/hola.rb` is not meant to be part of the file, but rather the whole thing is command-line output. `cat` is a command used to output the contents of a file, and things like `%` and `$` are often used to denote the start of a command. So, remove the first line from the file.